# Selecting test and train sets in Keras for Python

Tags: python, deep-learning, classification, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use Keras in Python for time series classification.

**I have made a simple CNN and was wondering if it is possible to randomly select a subsection of the full data set at each epoch to serve as the test set?**

I am quite new to neural nets so if there are any reasons this is impossible or impractical I would appreciate clarity.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set

Comment: In brief, a test set can't be a part of the train set because then you're effectively checking the same facts as those that your model was told to regard as true. I.e. this doesn't actually test or utilize the model's predictive power, only gives false reassurance.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not impossible, but it is impractical. A Neural Network learns from the training dataset. If you give the same data again in the test set, it will generate accurate predictions, which will have no relation with the network's predictive power.